# IIS ARR - Multiple Reverse Proxys

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

Is this possible?

We have setup ARR on our server and added a new binding for SSL and URL Rewrite using the Reverse Proxy rule, and it works fine.

Would it be possible to edit this, so say for example...

```
Binding Address: server1
https://server1/portal/server2 > Uses ARR to go to http://server2 internally.
https://server1/portal/server3 > Uses ARR to go to http://server3 internally.
```

What im trying to say, is it possible to have multiple reverse proxy's from one site's binding using URL Rewrite?

Or is it possible to build something like that in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this should work just fine. The only thing you have to take care off is that you use outbound rewriting to modify the URL's in the content from `server2` and `server3` to add `/portal/server2` and `/portal/server3` to any URL's otherwise static content might not load and links to internal pages might not point to the correct URL's.